# Can i use SideQuest to install my Uniity game on my Oculus Quest 2 with OpenXR enabled, or do i need the Oculus Selection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, openxr

Can i use SideQuest to install my Uniity game on my Oculus Quest 2 with OpenXR enabled, or do i need the Oculus Selection? Hello, I am Oculus Developer CubeHead making my VR Game, Conco Land. I was following a tutorial, and in the XR Plug-in Management, i want to use Oculus, since that means i should be able to install it on my headset with SideQuest (it's a sidequest game) But the tutorial says to use OpenXR. I have no idea on what to choose, and i'm probably just going to use Oculus and hope it works. Thanks.

I tried nothing, i am expecting it to work on SideQuest and for my game beta to export as an APK.